# card keeps clipping to position instead of animating

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When i try to use animations then it moves upa a bit but changes the 1st postion of the grid to be even higher and then clips to it. I want it to move slowly to the 1st position after the other cards are gone. here is the css:

```
.right-column {
    margin-top: 20px;
    flex: 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 50px;
    max-width: 500px; 
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: translateY(0); 
    transition: transform 0.3s ease; 
    order: 1; 
    
}

.active-card {
    z-index: 1; 
    order: -1;
}
.hidden-card {
    animation: moveOut 0.5s forwards;
}

.selected-card {
    z-index: 1; 
    top: 0; 
    transition: top 1.3s ease;
}

@keyframes moveOut {
    to {
        transform: translateX(100%); /* Move cards off the screen */
        opacity: 0; /* Hide cards */
        display: none;
    }
    
}
```

and here is the js section:

```
return (
    <div className="right-column">
      {cardsData.map((card) => (
        <div
        key={card.name}
        className={`card ${
          activeCard === 'all'
            ? 'active-card'
            : activeCard === card.name
            ? 'selected-card'
            : 'hidden-card'
            }`}
            onClick={() => handleCardClick(card.name)}
        >
          <h2>{card.name}</h2>
          {activeCard === card.name && <p>{card.content}</p>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

the selected-card is where i want the animation to happen. any help would be appreciated.